# How to test my selenium web test cases on mweb

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have few selenium test cases; running fine on desktop website. My website is responsive; hence works fine on Mobile Browser also. How do I test my test cases on Mobile Browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement is to test your site in Mobile view (As your site is responsive) then following code may help you -

```
 FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
 ffprofile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", "iPhone"); //this will change the user agent which will open mobile browser 
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile); 
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(360,640)); //just to change the window size so that it will look like mobile
 driver.get(siteURL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Appium](http://appium.io/introduction.html?lang=en) to support the

> Mobile web apps are web apps accessed using a mobile browser (Appium supports Safari on iOS and Chrome or the built-in ‘Browser’ app on Android).

Its design is based on the [WebDriver API](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/), so you’re free to use whatever test runner and test framework you already have. Keeping this in mind, your current [Test engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_execution_engine) should be insensitive to the application drivers and those are just plug&play “automation libraries” anyway.

Here is the Appium [GitHub examples repo](https://github.com/appium/sample-code), which I like to use. You can find examples in:

- RobotFramework
- dotnet
- java
- node
- perl
- php
- python
- ruby